# Edit and update a running instance variable in a separate class

Tags: java, action, jcolorchooser

I am making a Simon Says style game, there are four colored squares and the computer does a sequence, then you copy that, etc. and am at a point where I want to add some more advanced features. The current feature I am looking at is looking to change the color panels actual colors at the users will and being able to change them individually from one another.

How can I get the 'color panel(s)' to change to a new color via JColorChooser while keeping everything else set up?

At the moment I have it split up into a few different classes and am having issues getting them all to communicate and just work properly.

Main class(Only a snippet):

```
public class Simonish implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

private ColorPanel colorPanel[] = new ColorPanel[4];
private ScorePanel scorePanel = new ScorePanel();
private Menu menuBar = new Menu();
private JPanel gameBoard = new JPanel();
private Random rand = new Random();
private ArrayList<ColorPanel> compSeq = new ArrayList<ColorPanel>();
private Iterator<ColorPanel> iter;
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private boolean playerTurn = false;
private int speed = 500;

public Simonish(Color[] colors){
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    gameBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    gameBoard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));

    for (int i=0;i<colorPanel.length;i++){
        colorPanel[i] = new ColorPanel(colors[i]);
        colorPanel[i].addMouseListener(this);
        gameBoard.add(colorPanel[i]);
    }

    scorePanel.addStartListener(this);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    pane.add(scorePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

My Menu code (builds the menubar and implements the actions):

```
public class Menu extends JMenuBar {

private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

private JMenu settings = new JMenu("Settings");
private JMenu stats = new JMenu("Stats");
private JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");

private JMenuItem chooseColor = new JMenuItem(new ChooseColorAction("Choose Color"));
private JMenuItem colorMode = new JMenuItem(new ColorModeAction("Color Mode"));
private JMenuItem hScore = new JMenuItem("High Scores");
private JMenuItem history = new JMenuItem("History");
private JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
private JMenuItem rules = new JMenuItem("Rules");

public Menu(){
    this.add(settings);
    this.add(stats);
    this.add(help);

    settings.add(chooseColor);
    settings.add(colorMode);

    stats.add(hScore);
    stats.add(history);

    help.add(about);
    help.add(rules);
}
}
```

Action class to house the color changing code:

```
public class ColorModeAction extends AbstractAction {

public ColorModeAction(String name){
    super(name);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Color[] colors = {Color.CYAN, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN};
    //new Simonish(colors);
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Color Mode");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use interfaces to communicate your classes. For example; `ColorModeAction` needs to change colors so it should take an interface as parameter which able to change colors:

```
public interface ColorChanger {

    public void changeColor(int index, Color newColor);
}
```

Make Simonish implement that interface:

```
public class Simonish implements ActionListener, MouseListener, ColorChanger  {

    public void changeColor(int index, Color new Color) {
        //Change the given panel's color
    }
}
```

Pass `Simonish` as parameter to the menu, and move `new ColorModeAction("Color Mode")` to the constructor. Then pass `ColorChanger` to the `ColorModeAction` as a parameter.

```
public class Menu extends JMenuBar {

    ...
    private JMenuItem colorMode;
    ...

    public class Menu(ColorChanger colorChanger) {
         colorMode = new JMenuItem(new ColorModeAction(colorChanger, "Color Mode"));
    }
}
```

And the new `ColorModeAction`:

```
public class ColorModeAction extends AbstractAction {

    private ColorChanger colorChanger;

    public ColorModeAction(ColorChanger colorChanger, String name) {
        super(name);

        this.colorChanger = colorChanger;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Color[] colors = { Color.CYAN, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN };

        colorChanger.changeColor(index, Color)

    }
}
```

It is not fully working code but I think you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think I get it. I will try this out tonight.

Comment: Happy to help. You can search with "loosely coupling" keyword to understand why communication via interface is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks again, I like learning via some trial and error along with my own research, but sometimes I get stuck and just have no idea what to research, so thanks for the guidance.